# Битрикс задать значение свойства типа “Дата” для элемента инфоблока через API

Tags: php, битрикс

Как задать значение свойства типа "Дата" для существующего элемента инфоблока через api?

Использую код ниже, но не работает:

```
$productId = 267556;
$elementModel = new CIBlockElement();
$elementModel->SetPropertyValuesEx(
    $productId,
    IBLOCK_CATALOG_ID,
    ['DUMMY_UPDATED_AT' => date('Y-m-d')]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так заработало:

```
$productId = 267556;
$elementModel = new CIBlockElement();
$elementModel->SetPropertyValuesEx(
    $productId,
    IBLOCK_CATALOG_ID,
    ['DUMMY_UPDATED_AT' => date('d.m.Y H:i:s')]
);
```